# What to put for D-U-N-S number?

Tags: business, name

If our legal business name is Example Inc, should we include the "Inc" ending in our tradestyle? Or, should we just put Example for our tradestyle? We do not have a DBA name, and we want to use Example (without the Inc suffix) in marketing communications.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a law governing this choice?

Comment: No, I just don't understand what to put for tradestyle based on what we want. For example, would Apple put Apple Inc. or Apple?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about law.

Answer (score 1):

You may pick any name you want to get the number: you are also not required to use the exact name that you register as a trademark (if you do). You may include Inc, or you may leave it off. [DNB Germany](https://www.upik.de/61f2f34f91abd3e4f4fd4042602730f0/en/features_tradename_popup.html) says the trade style and registered name often differ.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. For example, would Apple put Apple Inc. or Apple?

Comment: What Apple "would do" is not a legal question. We also cannot advise you as to what you should do. I'm saying what you may do, legally, which is as far as you can go. I take it thought that you;re looking for legal advice.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what a tradestyle is. How about some real-life examples? Can you tell me the offical tradestyles of companies that have legal business names that end in Inc? For example, do you know any of the tradestyles of the following companies: Apple, Facebook, Google, Twitter, PayPal, Venmo, GitHub, Square? If not, how can I look them up?

Comment: You're the one who invoked "tradestyle". It means whatever you want it to mean.

Comment: You can just call D&B if you want to know what most firms do.  Since you're talking about registering for a private database, whether or not "Inc." is a noise word is less important than in other contexts (secured transactions, for example).

Comment: "Tradestyle" was the word used by D&B with regard to Apple's request to fill out basic business information. Isn't D&B's database public?